# Christoffel symbol for parabolic coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I am wondering why am I getting all the Christoffel symbol for the parabolic co-ordinates 
$$p(x, y) =x \qquad q(x, y) = y - x^2/2$$ ZERO ? The metric for this co-ordinate is $$ g^{\alpha\beta} = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & -p \\
-p & 1 + p^2 \end{array} \right)$$
or
$$ g_{\alpha\beta} = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 + p^2 & p \\
p & 1  \end{array} \right).$$

Comment: Why would someone down vote it without giving a reason ?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Well I am sure connections are zero. I am just looking for a good answer to physically explain why ?

Comment: I made a mistake there is one connection that is non-zero $\Gamma^q_{pp}$. I think the thread is not entirely useless as we have an example where only one connection encodes the co-ordinate curvature.

Answer (score 1):

While the OP made a mistake in calculation and not all $\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}$ are zero, one can ask what are the conditions on the metric for all $\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}$ to be zero.

In order to answer that question, one must first see up to which equivalence class does connection determine the metric. Well, if the connection $\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}$ is compatible with the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, then, by definition, the following differential equation must hold:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_\rho g_{\mu\nu}=0
\end{equation}

This is the first order differential equation, so it has one constant of integration - if you know the metric in one point, then the connection determines it uniquely.

Now, for the case $\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}=0$,the above equation reduces to
\begin{equation}
\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu}=0.
\end{equation}

The conclusion is: **Connection vanishes if and only if the metric tensor is constant.**

Therefore, if you get your Christoffels equal to zero for non-constant metric, then it is easy to see that you made a mistake in your calculation.

Comment: The conclusion here is correct, but be wary of talking about constants of integration (and the number thereof) when dealing with *partial* differential equations.